# Java: Adding raw data to payload Httpost request

Tags: java, http-post, payload

I intend to send a simple http post request with a large string in the Payload.

So far I have the following.

```
    DefaultHttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();


    HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("address location");

    String cred = "un:pw";

    byte[] authEncBytes = Base64.encodeBase64(cred.getBytes());
    String authStringEnc = new String(authEncBytes);



    httppost.setHeader("Authorization","Basic " + authStringEnc);
```

However, I do not know how to attach a simple RAW string into the payload. The only examples I can find are name value pairs into the Entity but this is not what I want.

Any assistance?

Comment: Take a look to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12842430/java-http-post-request?rq=1 or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13396171/send-http-post-payload-with-java?rq=1

Answer (score 9):

It depends on the concrete HTTP-API you're using:

**Commons HttpClient (old - end of life)**

Since HttpClient 3.0 you can specify a `RequestEntity` for your `PostMethod`:

```
httpPost.setRequestEntity(new StringRequestEntity(stringData));
```

Implementations of `RequestEntity` for binary data are `ByteArrayRequestEntity` for `byte[]`, `FileRequestEntity` which reads the data from a file (since 3.1) and `InputStreamRequestEntity`, which can read from any input stream.

Before 3.0 you can directly set a `String` or an `InputStream`, e.g. a `ByteArrayInputStream`, as request body:

```
httpPost.setRequestBody(stringData);
```

or

```
httpPost.setRequestBody(new ByteArrayInputStream(byteArray));
```

This methods are deprecated now.

**HTTP components (new)**

If you use the newer [HTTP components](http://hc.apache.org/) API, the method, class and interface names changed a little bit, but the concept is the same:

```
httpPost.setEntity(new StringEntity(stringData));
```

Other `Entity` implementations: `ByteArrayEntity`, `InputStreamEntity`, `FileEntity`, ...

Answer (score 1):

i was making a common mistake sequence of json object was wrong. for example i was sending it like first_name,email..etc..where as correct sequence was email,first_name

my code

```
boolean result = false;
    HttpClient hc = new DefaultHttpClient();
    String message;

HttpPost p = new HttpPost(url);
JSONObject object = new JSONObject();
try {

    object.put("updates", updates);
    object.put("mobile", mobile);
    object.put("last_name", lastname);
    object.put("first_name", firstname);
    object.put("email", email);

} catch (Exception ex) {

}

try {
message = object.toString();


p.setEntity(new StringEntity(message, "UTF8"));
p.setHeader("Content-type", "application/json");
    HttpResponse resp = hc.execute(p);
    if (resp != null) {
        if (resp.getStatusLine().getStatusCode() == 204)
            result = true;
    }

    Log.d("Status line", "" + resp.getStatusLine().getStatusCode());
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();

}

return result;
```

[Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6533234/how-to-make-httppost-call-with-json-encoded-body)